# Tried to apply Spring security on struts2 but it does not work

Tags: java, struts2, spring-security

I have the following code to apply Spring security on struts2 but it allows user to see a secured page although I have not implement the datasource part (because I do not know how) yet but I do not expect it to enable unauthorized users open the page.

`Web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/*-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

my jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
    <sec:authorize ifAllGranted="ROLE_ADMIN">
        <a href="<s:url namespace ="/Profile" action="view.action"/>" >Profile</a>
    </sec:authorize>
```

my secured method

```
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Action;
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured;

@Action
public class Profile{

    @Secured ({"ROLE_ADMIN"})
    public String view(){
        System.out.println("view");
        return "View"; 
    }
```

Security-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <!-- Restrict URLs based on role -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/logoutSuccess*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/css/main.css" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

        <!-- Override default login and logout pages -->
        <security:form-login login-page="/login.html" 
                             login-processing-url="/loginProcess" 
                             default-target-url="/index.jsp" 
                             authentication-failure-url="/login.html?login_error=1" />
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/logoutSuccess.html" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider >
            <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

Comment: provide your jsp as well.

Comment: shouldn't the annotation like this: `@Secured ("ROLE_ADMIN")`

Comment: What do you mean on "I have not implement the datasource part"? You have a configured jdbc-user-service in your security context, so if your application starts up, I suppose you have a database with the proper user table schema as described in appendix A of the Spring Security reference docs. If that's the case, your database content determines what authorities users have.

Comment: If you want to start with a simpler setup and check if the rest of your config works, try first using the in-memory user service as described in http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/ns-config.html#ns-minimal

Comment: Some tips: 1. Please set `security` as the default namespace in your `security-context.xml`; you'll save yourself some typing. 2. Use of `ifAllGranted="ROLE_ADMIN"` is deprecated. Instead use `hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to protect your struts application by URLs you need to ensure to have the  for springSecurityFilterChain before the struts2 . The configuration you have posted does not appear to have the springSecurityFilterChain  at all. In short, update your configuration as follows:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<!-- The order of filter-mapping is important springSecurityFilterChain should be first! -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The above setup will protect your application using URL based security. However, in order to secure your application with method based security you need to ensure that you are allowing Spring to create your objects that are annotated with @Secured. To do this, ensure you have followed the instructions on [integrating Spring and Struts](http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html#struts) provided within the reference.

Comment: I used springsecurityFilterchain, I have already mentioned it in my question after context-param

Comment: You don't have a `filter-mapping` for it. Compare your file with Rob's answer.